# Creating a generic payments library

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to create Payment Gateway abstraction, for one of my projects using Asp.Net Core, so that clients can integrate their payment gateways, by creating derived libraries. My application will load the derived libraries and call the methods.

Below is an interface that all payment gateways must implement. This lies in the Core library, let's call it **PaymentGateway.Core.dll**. This library is part of the main application.

```
namespace PaymentGateway.Core
{

    public interface IPaymentGateway
    {

        string Name { get; }

        // The purpose of this function is to transform the order details into an object, 
        // as expected by the underlying gateway's apis
        object CreatePaymentRequest(Order request);

        // The purpose of this function is to transform the payment response object,
        // received from the payment gateway api, 
        // into an application entity that represents this payment.
        Payment ProcessPaymentResponse(object response);

    }

    // Order for which the payment to be collected. This entity is stored in DB
    public class Order
    {
        string UserId { get; set; }

        string ProductId { get; set; }

        double OrderTotal { get; set; }
    }

    // A payment attempted for an Order. This entity is stored in DB
    public class Payment
    {
        Order Order { get; set; }

        string PaymentGateway { get; set; }

        double Amount { get; set; }

        PaymentStatus Status { get; set; } // Failed, User Aborted, Success
    }
}
```

Below is an example of PayPal integration library, let's call it **PaymentGateway.PayPal.dll**. This library references the core library and implements the PaymentGateway interface.

```
namespace PaymentGateway.PayPal
{
    class PayPal : IPaymentGateway
    {
        public string Name { get => "PayPal"; }

        public object CreatePaymentRequest(Order request)
        {
            :
            :
        }


        public Payment ProcessPaymentResponse(object response)
        {
            :
            :
        }
    }
}
```

The process flow in the core library to execute a payment would be like :

1. The buyer clicks on the PayPal button on the webpage.
2. The core application then initializes the PayPal object.
3. The core application then calls the CreatePaymentrequest() function with the order details. The function will transform the order details into PayPal Payment Request format.
4. The returned data is passed to PayPal apis to initiate a transaction.
5. After PayPal api finishes, it returns the response in a its defined format.
6. The response from PayPal api is passed to the server, which calls ProcessPaymentResponse() on the PayPal object. This function transform the response into Payment object.

The problem i have is that the application ( Core ) doesn't understand the return type of CreatePaymentRequest(), as it is depends on the called gateway. Similarly, for ProcessPaymentResponse() the argument type is gateway specific and the type will be defined in the gateway library.

For now i am forced to use System.Object. Is there any better solution to the problem ?

Comment: I do not see anywhere in your code where Core needs to understand anything about the response. if it does, you have to decide exactly *what* it needs to understand.  What properties or methods does it need to be present in the response in order to do its job? You would then put those properties or methods into an interface and use that instead of `object`.

Comment: @JohnWu I agree to your suggestion of creating IPaymentRequest and IPaymentResponse interfaces, and using them instead of **object**. That way core gets the required understanding of the generated request / response, ignoring all other gateway specific details. Probably, I went too far trying to control everything ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface IPaymentGateway<T> where T : class
{
    string Name { get; }
    T CreatePaymentRequest(PaymentRequest request);
    PaymentResponse ProcessPaymentResponse(T response);
}

public class PayPal<T> : IPaymentGateway<T> where T : class
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public T CreatePaymentRequest(PaymentRequest request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public PaymentResponse ProcessPaymentResponse(T response)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public void ExampleMethod()
    {
        IPaymentGateway<Foo> paypal = new PayPal<Foo>();
        var name = paypal.Name;
        Foo paymentRequest = paypal.CreatePaymentRequest(new PaymentRequest());
        var paymentResponse = paypal.ProcessPaymentResponse(new Foo());
    }
}


public class Foo
{
}

public class PaymentResponse
{
}

public class PaymentRequest
{
}
```

Instead of returning an `object` why not make it generic and have them pass in the type?

Comment: I'm not sure on that. How will my base / core class know about the Type ?

Comment: Make the class use `<T>` instead of the methods, then everything knows inside of it and it's only done once.

Comment: I tried it, but then i get a compiler warning that the interface is not implemented. Compiler expects the derived class to use <T> and not any concrete type.

Comment: Make your interface generic

Comment: I'll try that, but i don't think it will work. Since PaymentRequest, and PaymentResponse will be two different classes, unlike in your example where same generic is used for both of them.

Comment: It will be better, if you can post a pseudo code of your recommended solution. Please include both the interface and it's derived class, in the pseudo code.

Comment: Added a more involved example. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This won't work, as Example class will be part of the core application, which is not dependent on the payment gateway. Please refer the updated question, i've added more pseudo code and example work-flow to give clarity on how the entire system is supposed to work.

Comment: @PraveenRai either I'm not understanding your actual issue or you're not getting generics correctly, either way I don't know what else to offer behind what I have.